# REST API - JSON mapping to object

Tags: json, rest, api, object, mapper

I have the following JSON object via a REST API and I want to convert it to POJO-s - object. I did it on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ website an received the code bellow. I just cannot successfully map JSON to object data.

```
{"categories":[{"categories":{"id":1,"name":"Delivery"}},{"categories":{"id":2,"name":"Dine-out"}},{"categories":{"id":3,"name":"Nightlife"}},{"categories":{"id":4,"name":"Catching-up"}},{"categories":{"id":5,"name":"Takeaway"}},{"categories":{"id":6,"name":"Cafes"}},{"categories":{"id":7,"name":"Daily Menus"}},{"categories":{"id":8,"name":"Breakfast"}},{"categories":{"id":9,"name":"Lunch"}},{"categories":{"id":10,"name":"Dinner"}},{"categories":{"id":11,"name":"Pubs & Bars"}},{"categories":{"id":12,"name":"Premium Delivery"}},{"categories":{"id":13,"name":"Pocket Friendly Delivery"}},{"categories":{"id":14,"name":"Clubs & Lounges"}}]}
```

Here is Model from REST API website:

//MODEL:

```
Inline Model [
Categories
]
Categories {
category_id (integer): ID of the category type ,
category_name (string): Name of the category type
}
```

//MODEl Schema

```
[
  {
    "category_id": "3",
    "category_name": "Nightlife"
  }
]
```

Generated POJOs:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"name"
})
public class Categories {

@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

/**
*
* @return
* The id
*/
@JsonProperty("id")
public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

/**
*
* @param id
* The id
*/
@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The name
*/
@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
*
* @param name
* The name
*/
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;``
}
}

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"categories"
})
public class Category {

@JsonProperty("categories")
private Categories categories;

/**
*
* @return
* The categories
*/
@JsonProperty("categories")
public Categories getCategories() {
return categories;
}

/**
*
* @param categories
* The categories
*/
@JsonProperty("categories")
public void setCategories(Categories categories) {
this.categories = categories;
}

}

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"categories"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("categories")
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

/**
*
* @return
* The categories
*/
@JsonProperty("categories")
public List<Category> getCategories() {
return categories;
}

/**
*
* @param categories
* The categories
*/
@JsonProperty("categories")
public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
this.categories = categories;
}

}
```

Will you, please, help me with proper mapper definition?

Comment: That generated code is fairly dirty, you should tidy it up a little. From a quick glance, it looks like you can delete most of the annotations. To solve your actual question, do the mapping in reverse. i.e. Generate json from your java object and compare it with your desired output.

Comment: I am using REST API from website that allows me and need to convert Java bean.  My input data is JSON and output should be Java bean. I, probably, need to ignore some properties such as categories (displayed in 2 places in JSON array).

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but you can significantly tidy up the code. Then use the code to generate json and compare it with your desired json to try and figure out what is wrong

Comment: Daniel, the JSON is generated from RESTAPI url in the format as I it displayed on the top of the post. My question is how to create bean (list of beans) from the generated JSON using mappers.

Comment: OK, so I must be missing something - it looks like you have the bean already, no? What's not working.